# Fast(er) way to determine all non-dominated items in a list

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list of *n* arrays with 4 elements each, i.e (*n*=2):

```
l = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]]
```

and am trying to find all elements of the list that are 'non-dominated' - that is they are not dominated by any other element in the list. An array dominates another array if each item inside it is less than or equal to the corresponding item in the other array. So

```
dominates([1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]) == True
```

as `1 <= 5 and 2 <= 6 and 3 <= 7 and 4 <= 8`. But

```
dominates([1, 2, 3, 9], [5, 6, 7, 8]) == False
```

as `9 > 8`. This function is relatively easy to write, for example:

```
def dominates(a, b):
    return all(i <= j for i, j in zip(a, b))
```

More succinctly, given `l = [a1, a2, a3, .., an]` where the `a` are length 4 arrays, I'm looking to find all `a` that are not dominated by any other `a in l`.

I have the following solution:

```
def get_non_dominated(l):
    to_remove = set()
    for ind, item_1 in enumerate(l):
        if item_2 in to_remove:
            continue
        for item_2 in l[ind + 1:]:
            if dominates(item_2, item_1):
                to_remove.add(item_1)
                break
            elif dominates(item_1, item_2):
                to_remove.add(item_2)
    return [i for i in l if i not in to_remove]
```

So `get_non_dominated([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]])` should return `[[1, 2, 3, 4]]`. Similarly `get_non_dominated([[1, 2, 3, 9], [5, 6, 7, 8]])` should return the list unchanged by the logic above (nothing dominates anything else).

But this check happens a lot and `l` is potentially quite large. I was wondering if anyone had ideas on a way to speed this up? My first thought was to try and vectorize this code with numpy, but I have relatively little experience with it and am struggling a bit. You can assume `l` has all unique arrays. Any ideas are greatly appreciated!

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are trying to achieve. Please update your question to include working code with examplary input and output.

Comment: I added some extra detail that hopefully cleared it up a bit.

Comment: Updated the answer to reflect the filtering that you want (which by chance was the example that I was showing).

Answer (score 4):

Another version of @Nyps answer:

```
def dominates(a, b):
    return (np.asarray(a) <= b).all()
```

It is the vectorized approach of your code using numpy.

---

This might still be slow if you have to loop through all the rows you have. If you have a list with all the rows and you want to compare them pairwise, you could use scipy to create a `N x N` array (where `N` is the number of rows).

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(1000, 10))
```

`a` here is a `1000 x 10` array, simulating `1000` rows of `10` elements it:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
X = cdist(a, a, metric=dominates).astype(np.bool)
```

`X` is now a `1000 x 1000` matrix containing the pairwise comparison between all the entries. This is, `X[i, j]` contains `True` if sample `i` dominates sample `j` or `False` otherwise.

You can now extract fancy results from `X`, such as the sample that dominates them all:

```
>>> a[50] = 0 # set a row to all 0s to fake a dominant row
>>> X = cdist(a, a, metric=dominates).astype(np.bool)
>>> non_dominated = np.where(X.all(axis=1))[0]
>>> non_dominated
array([50])
```

Sample at position `50` is the ruler if your population, you should watch it closely.

---

Now, if you want to preserve only the dominated you can do:

```
if non_dominated.size > 0:
    return [a[i] for i in non_dominated]
else: # no one dominates every other
    return a
```

As a recap:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

def get_ruler(a):
    X = cdist(a, a, metric=dominates).astype(np.bool)
    rulers = np.where(X.all(axis=1))[0]
    if rulers.size > 0:
        return [a[i] for i in rulers]
    else: # no one dominates every other
        return a
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! The second part using scipy is in the realm of what I am looking for, but rather than finding rows that dominate other rows, I need all rows that are **not** dominated by any other rows. I think that should be fairly straightforward to extract from what you have - thanks for much again!

Comment: @user8415803 Ops true! I did change the name to `get_ruler` for the example. In your case, if I did understand properly, you want to check the column `j` rather than the row `i` (change to `axis=0`). Although, it is not equivalent? I mean, if a row is **not dominated** by any other row, does it not imply that it **does dominate** every other row? (just curious, my logic might be playing with me).

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
import numpy as np
np.all((np.asarry(l[1])-np.asarry(l[0]))>=0)
```

You can go a simliar way in case you are able to create your list as numpy array straight away, i.e. `type(l) == np.ndarray`. Then the syntax would be:

```
np.all(p[1])-p[0])>=0)
```

Comment: `np.all` should be faster.